# How to immediately finish ongoing animation?

Tags: jquery

User starts the animation by mouseenter. But when he mouseenter on other element to start next animation, I want to immediately finish previous. Animation you can see on the website www.checkitout.over.cz/appio. Thanks to all.

```
$(".col3-1 > div").mouseenter(function(){

        $(this).find("div").find("span").hide();
        $(this).find("div").find("div").hide();
        $(this).find("div").css("height", "1.5em");
        $(this).find("div").find("div").css("top", "0px");
        $(this).find("div").find("div").fadeIn();

            $(this).find("div").find("div").animate({
                "left": "78px"
            }, 200);

    });


    $(".col3-1 > div").mouseleave(function(){

        $(this).find("div").find("span").show();
        $(this).find("div").css("height", "2.5em");
        $(this).find("div").find("div").css("top", "7px");
        $(this).find("div").find("div").css("left", "10px");

    });
```

Comment: what about `.finish()` on jq 1.9+ or `.stop(true, true)` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is what you need.

`stop()` stops the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

you can pass extra parameters to stop,

```
stop(true,true)
```

which clears the queue and complete the current animation immediately is set to true

and why do you have two `find()`. seperating them with space should work

```
$(this).find("div span")..
```

Comment: Maybe what OP is looking for but doesn't finish animation, just stop it

Comment: OP can pass parameters as stop(true,true) for that. inculiding it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use `finish()` method: (jq 1.9+)

```
$('.col3-1 > div:animated').finish();
```

For older jq version, use `stop(true, true)`:

```
$('.col3-1 > div:animated').stop(true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method

```
$(this).find("div").find("div").stop().animate({
            "left": "78px"
        }, 200);
  );
```